Convex combination of positive semi-definite operators and a simple relationship between the images of the operators involved
Let $V$ be an Euclidean vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $A,B: V \longrightarrow V$ positive semi-definite operators on $V$. Let $\lambda \in (0,1)$.
Then $P:=\lambda A + (1-\lambda)B$ is also positive semi-definite. Why is it true that
$\mathrm{im}(A) \subseteq \mathrm{im}(P)$ (and therefore also $\mathrm{im}(B)\subseteq \mathrm{im}(P)$)?

For positive definite operators $X,Y$, the image of $X + Y$ contains both that of $X$ and $Y$. It suffices to apply your observations to $X = \lambda A$ and $Y = (1 - \lambda)B$, noting
$$
\text{im}(\lambda A) = \text{im}(A), \quad \text{im}((1 - \lambda)B) = \text{im}(B).
$$
To see this general fact about the sum of positive definite operators, you can use the logic I apply in this post to conclude that $\ker(X) \supseteq \ker(X + Y)$, hence $\ker(X)^\perp \subseteq \ker(X + Y)^\perp $, hence $\text{im}(X) \subseteq \text{im}(X + Y)$.

Thank you very much.
